# Altitude differences in different CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, altitude

Currently I am working on a project in Kosovo. After gaining autonomy the country "invented" their own CRS, which is driving me crazy sometimes. It doesn't even have an EPSG-Code, it goes by "Kosova Ref 01" and the [SR-ORG 7392, 9079 and 9080](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/9080/).

I managed usual reprojecting, but today I encountered a significant difference in altitude. While e.g. Google Earth and some surveyor-data state, that the area is I am working on is between 1450 and 1600 m above sealevel, data using the Kosova Ref 01 says it is about 40 to 45 m higher. Is this possible, or did someone (maybe me) botch something?

tl;dr: Is an altitude difference of about 40 m between two CRS feasible?

Comment: Not sure how Kosova Ref 01 can tell you anything about altitude as it's only a 2D CRS

Comment: I suppose it's got something to do with the ellipsoid the CRS is based on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely the difference between the ellipsoid surface and the geoid / gravity-related vertical coordinate system in the area. I used Charles Karney's [online geoid calculator](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeoidEval?input=42d40%27N+21d10%27E&option=Submit) to check a point in Pristina. The geoid undulation is about 45.7 m there.